# Synthesize camphene

Tags: synthesis, solvents

How does one easily synthesize camphene in the modern day? The old 1902 patent says to combine ammonia and pinene hydrochloride in an autoclave at 210-220C for 20 hours. Would alpha-pinene work with that process?

Answer (score 1):

1. alpha-pinene can be isomerized using acid treated clay as the catalyst to produce camphene. (see references in the comments below)
2. Isolated Camphene can be naturally sourced from valerian (Valeriana officinalis) extracted via steam, expression, or cryogenic methods, and fractionally distilled for purity http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10412905.2008.9700079

Comment: Could you provide a reference or additional details regarding your answer?

Comment: Alpha-pinene isomerization on acid-treated clays
Nurgün Be˛sün a,∗, Fehime Özkan b, Gönül Gündüz a
a Ege University, Faculty of Engineering, Chemical Engineering Department, 35100 Bornova, ˙
Izmir, Turkey b Izmir Institute of Technology, Faculty of Engineering, Chemical Engineering Department, 35230 Çankaya, ˙
Izmir, Turkey

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926860X01008523

Comment: Isomerization of Alpha-pinene Over Acid Treated Natural Zeolite
Ercan Ünveren , Gönül Gündüz  & Fehime Cakicioğlu–Özkan
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00986440590477773